# DataTable empty after .load(SqlDataReader)

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, sqldatareader

After I run DataTable.load(SqlDataReader), the DataTable seems to be empty, but the DataReader contains results (can be seen while debugging).

Can anyone help me with this one please? I can't seem to find any solution for this problem, nor can't I find a mistake in my algorithm..
I found some solutions for using a DataAdapter & Fill(), but I'm just curious about this 'problem'.
My code:

```
DataTable DeviceProperties = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT PropertyID, PropertyName from DeviceProperties WHERE DeviceID = @DeviceID;";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSelectDeviceProperties = new SqlCommand(query, connectionDBTest))
            {
                cmdSelectDeviceProperties.Parameters.Add("@DeviceID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = deviceID;
                using (SqlDataReader rdrSelectDeviceProperties = cmdSelectDeviceProperties.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rdrSelectDeviceProperties.HasRows)
                        DeviceProperties.Load(rdrSelectDeviceProperties);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("No Device Properties found..");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getDeviceProperties: " + ex);
        }
        return DeviceProperties;
```

FYI: the rdrSelectDeviceProperties.HasRows passes every time, so the reader certainly contains some value.. The correct results can be found in the rdrSelectDeviceProperties, during debugging.. But the DeviceProperties data table remains empty..

**EXACT PROBLEM:** the data table seemed empty while debugging, because the hover over showed: '{ }'. 
The rest of the code, depending on the data table, responded as the data table was empty.
**SOLUTION:** When you press the magnifying glass and you get the representation of the data in the data table.
My mistake was in the rest of the code (comparing the data in the data table with string, without using '.ToString()').

Learn from my mistakes..

Comment: Have you tried `using(var daSelectDeviceProperties = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionDBTest)) daSelectDeviceProperties.Fill(DeviceProperties);`instead?
`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but can you elaborate a little bit more on where to put the above code?
And on a second note, I was kinda wondering why the DataTable DeviceProperties was empty, even after I used load on a SqlReader which contains results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's causing this issue but i would use `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)` instead of `DataTable.Load(sqlDatareader)`:

```
DataTable tblSelectDeviceProperties = new DataTable();
using (var daSelectDeviceProperties = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionDBTest))
{
    // no need to open/close the connection with DataAdapter.Fill
    daSelectDeviceProperties.Fill(tblSelectDeviceProperties);   
}
if (tblSelectDeviceProperties.Rows.Count == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("No Device Properties found..");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I think I found out what the 'problem' is.
While debugging, the data table preview looks empty ( '{ }' is shown), but still the data table was filled with the result from the data reader. The reason why the rest of my program didn't do anything, is because I made a mistake with indexing the table (happy happy joy joy!). But thanks a lot to the both of you and kinda sorry for wasting you time..

Comment: @user5110371: you can click on the loupe in the debugger to watch the DataTable data.

Comment: well yeah.. that kinda solved it too.. Well, this is just one of those days you kinda feel stupid.. :) thanks again for the response.